# Requested registry access is not allowed error in TFS folder compare

Tags: tfs

I am using Team foundation server 2012.Folder compare using batch file gives below error

```
"Requested registry access is not allowed"
```

The error comes only for .bmp file types.
If folders are compared manually in TFS no error occurs.

Batch file have following command

```
tf.exe folderdiff $/folder1 $/folder2
```

When batch file is normally run in admin and non- admin user account error comes. But in any user account right click on batch file "run as administrator" no error. The .bat file worked in other client machine.

Is there any method to solve this error?

Comment: If you run tf command directly from Developer Command for VS with non admin account, how's the result?

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: I have tried it didn't help.

Comment: If you run tf command directly from Developer Command for VS with non admin account, how's the result?

Comment: I am getting same error.

Comment: Do you have this issue on other machine?

Answer (score 0):

You may run `regedit` and navigate to the key that you are trying to access(something like: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\xx.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\FolderDifference`) with your script, right click on it and view the permissions, add try to add the non admin user and give it appropriate permission (Full Control, Read, Special Permissions).

[image]